# Cannot Trade in Team Fortess 2

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Team Fortress 2 is not letting me trade. It says, "Your account cannot trade right  now". I waited for 6 or 7 days but I still can't trade, what do I do?

Comment: Have you bought anything in the TF2 Store already?  Or been upgraded to a premium member though buying the game originally or getting the upgrade from someone?  ["Free" accounts cannot trade out, but can receive trades.](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Account_types)

Comment: Stupid question: Have you bought anything or added funds to the steam wallet with your account?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a premium account, which basically means you need to have bought a game or added funds to your Steam wallet to trade. Basically any kind of purchase on Steam validates you as a premium user rather than free "limited" users with limited rights.

Comment: Wrong-ish. To get premium, you need to purchase something from TF2 store, just adding wallet money / buying a game isn't enough. the cheapest thing is giftapult, which is 10 cents.

Comment: really? I haven't bought anything from the TF2 store, but I've bought 8 games, and I'm premium.

Comment: By any chance, did you buy "The Orange Box"?

Comment: I did not. My Steam library consists of Portal, Portal 2, TF2 (F2P), Drifter, Faster than Light, Gmod, The Stanley Parable, and a few other free games

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be due to Steam Guard. Try re-enabling it.

Answer (score -2):

This might be due to the fact that Steam was down around the time you were trying to trade. Everything was down, from inventory to servers.

You could try again or submit this question within the TF2 discussion page: http://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/

Comment: I doubt it, since he does mention he was unable to trade since last week.